# Which version of Rebol 2 do I use on CentOS?

Tags: cgi, centos, rebol

Can somebody please tell me which version of Rebol 2 to use on CentOS?

There are a couple of Linux versions on this page:

http://www.rebol.com/platforms.html

I'm going to have a go at this tutorial:
[Quick and Easy CGI - A Beginner's Tutorial and Guide](http://www.rebol.com/docs/cgi1.html) By Carl Sassenrath.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess, since CentOS is derived from Red Hat and so is Fedora, I would go with the Fedora build. But even if you choose incorrectly, you will probably find out fairly quickly that you've got the wrong package.